# Python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Tags: python, string

I'm completely new and learning Python.

I'm getting the error in title.
Should I convert the "str" to StringVar() ? If yes, how could I do it ?

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
    def count():
        print(user_entries[2].get())
        errorempty=""
        g=0
        h=0
        while g<nbofcalc:
            if user_entries[g].get() !="":
                h+=1
            else:
                h+=0
            g+=1
        print(h)
        hstr=str(h)
        if h==0:
            errorempty=Label(text="You have enter NO calculation number, please enter at least one", fg="red")
            errorempty.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        else:
            errorempty.destroy()
            errorempty=Label(text="Download  will start", fg="red")
            errorempty.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        
        
    boutoncount=Button(fenetre,text="count",width=800,height=1,bg="white", font="bold",bd=5, command=count)
    boutoncount.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcha02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Marcha02\Desktop\Python\Tkinter - GUI 3 - Entries with Loop.py", line 70, in count
    errorempty.destroy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

Thank you and sorry the "dirty" code, I started to learn some weeks ago.

Comment: Please add what you are trying to do in abstract so that more efficient code can be given to you. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to destroy a string, which can't be done. Fix it like this:

```
def count():
    print(user_entries[2].get())
    # remove this >>> errorempty=""
    g=0
    h=0
    while g<nbofcalc:
        if user_entries[g].get() !="":
            h+=1
        else:
            h+=0
        g+=1
    print(h)
    hstr=str(h)
    if h==0:
        errorempty=Label(text="You have enter NO calculation number, please enter at least one", fg="red")
        errorempty.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    else:
        # >>> and this if it is not a global variable too errorempty.destroy()
        errorempty=Label(text="Download  will start", fg="red")
        errorempty.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    
    
boutoncount=Button(fenetre,text="count",width=800,height=1,bg="white", font="bold",bd=5, command=count)
boutoncount.pack(side=BOTTOM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is on line 70. Line 70 itself is unneeded because you can simply reassign `errorempty` to the new object. To fix your problem, delete line 70.

Comment: If the user has not entered any input, then comes the error message from Label "You have entered No calculation numbers...". But if he following this message put an input, then the Label "Download will start" wil be displayed. the problem is that I need the get the first Label "You have entered NO..." deleted. Otherwise the new message will come above.

Comment: The message would never have been shown in the first place. Thats how if-else statements work. If and only if the boolean condition is true, then the first path will be taken, otherwise the `else` path will be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is set up now, `errorempty` is always equal to `""` when `errorempty.destroy()` is executed. `""` is a string, not at tkinter widget, so it does not have a destroy method. You therefore currently don't need that line.

In general, if you need to check if the object exists before destroying it, you could use the following:

```
if errorempty is not None:
    errorempty.destroy()
```

Note that it's better to change `errorempty=""` to `errorempty = None` since it's supposed to hold a `Label`, not a `str`. But in this case you do not need either of those lines, since you assign `errorempty` inside the if-statement.

---

Also consider heading over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once your code is working correctly, to get some tips about improving your code.

Comment: Thanks. There are 9 entries. The user can enter until 9 Calculation numbers to enable to download the doc.

h = number of calc numbers the user entered. To launch the download, he has to click on a button. 

(1) When he clicks on it, If he has not put any numbers =  the error message : "You have enter No calculation number".

(2)  So he can still enter new calculation number and click again and then the message "Download will start" comes.

Problem: the message of (1) remains and the one from (2) comes above the message. I want  (1) to disappear to let the message (2) displayed alone.